# Promise for loop - basic

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

What's the best way to loop through this Promise chain ? code works fine without the 'for loop' with last step saving JSON in MongoDB. After the first iteration NodeJS shell hangs.

```
for(i=0; i < 2; i++){
    forLoop(countOfFlights,jsonRead).then(function(fromResolve){
        return filter(fromResolve)
    }).then(function(fromResolve){
        return sort(fromResolve)
    }).then(function(fromResolve){
        saveMongoDB(fromResolve)
    })}
```

I checked some of the threads on Promise & looping, but the examples were too complicated for me. Perhaps just one magic line would solve it. I'm sure better understanding of why it hangs would be beneficial too.

Kind regards,

Comment: Try rewriting this with a Promise.all(), but that probably also includes rewriting the forloop() method you don't show here and might change the filter(), sort() functions as well, depending on their implementation. But rule of thumb, promises and for loops don't match well. Have you for loop return promises that you wrap in a promise.all() and then handle all the results as an array instead of handling each result seperately and looping the entire promise chain.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Shilly ! Before I try what you've recommended - can you perhaps suggest solution different to Promises ? I need to iterate over arrays coming from multiple files and post them to MongoDB. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

-comment continued-
You could just iterate synchronous, but that'll always be slower than just using promises. As long as the file inserts are not related to eachother, being able to insert them all at the same time without waiting to see if the prev insert succeeded is a win, so I'd personally stick with the promises.

I would aim for a structure like this:

```
// We want an array with promise objects.
// Since forLoop() returns a promise, we can call it twice
// I don't know if 'i' is used anywhere in your loop, so if you do need it,
// you can replace this with a loop that creates the arrays of promises.
var requests = [
    forLoop(countOfFlights,jsonRead), //
    forLoop(countOfFlights,jsonRead)
];
Promise.all(
    requests
 ).then(function( rawRes ) {
    return rawRes.map( filter );
}).then(function( filteredRes ) {
    return filteredRes.map( sort );
}).then(function( sortedRes ) {
    return sortedRes.map( saveMongoDB );
}).then(function( insertedRes ) {
    // Do something to check if the database inserts succeeded.
}).catch(function( errors ) {
    console.error( errors );
});
```

So the idea is to use the loop first to create a bunch of promises, then we run all the promises 'at the same time', and then handle all the results.

If for some reason you do want to handle each file seperately, put your code into a function and loop that function instead of the code directly. That does also imply you need some kind of counter or again a promise.all() to check when all the file inserts are completed:

```
var insertFile = function insertFile( count, json ) {
        return forLoop(
                count,
                json 
              ).then(function(fromResolve){
                return filter(fromResolve);
            }).then(function(fromResolve){
                return sort(fromResolve);
            }).then(function(fromResolve){
                return saveMongoDB(fromResolve);
            }).then(function( inserted ) {
                // do stuff seperately for an insert
                return inserted;
            }).catch(function( error ) {
                throw error;
            });
        });
    },
    i,
    requests = [];

for (i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
    requests.push( insertFile( countOfFlights, jsonReads ) );
}
Promise.all(
    requests
 ).then(function( responses ) {
    // all files are inserted
}).catch(function( error ) {
    // something went wrong
});
```

You might be able to merge the filter and sort callbacks into one `.reduce()`, but that's just a side remark since I don't know how .filter() and.sort() are coded.